# Keep previous value for state var that will be change in the future

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, state

I have multiple @State var that will be changed in the TextField, but I want to keep the old values to be used after the state values are changed on the TextFields

```
@State var name: String

var oldName = ???
```

What is the best approach for this?

Comment: @user1046037  `didSet` does not work with  a `@State` property wrapper

Comment: @vadian am I missing something? seems to work for me `@State private var name: String? { didSet { print("oldValue = \(oldValue ?? "nil")") }}`.

Comment: @user1046037 Please try `oldName = oldValue` in the `didSet` closure and display `oldName` in the view with `Text(oldName)`. Nothing will happen.

Comment: No, `didSet` will not work, because the `name` property is actually of type `State` (that's what the property wrapper is for). Changing the `$name` value never actually changes or sets the `State` property, so `didSet` will never be called.

Comment: I want to keep the old value, the initial one, before modifying the text field

Answer (score 2):

Updated to remember the *initial* name, not the previous name.

If you want to remember the initial name, it will have to be supplied by a parent view as regular constant. This way, it is decoupled from the modifiable state property that the `TextField` operates on. The only thing missing, now, is that the textfield needs to be pre-filled with the initial name. This can't (shouldn't) be done in the view's `init()`, but using a lifecycle event such as `.onAppear`.

```
struct TextFieldView: View {
    let initialName: String

    @State private var name: String
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Name", text: $name)
            .onAppear { self.name = initialName }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But it still does not work, it does not keep the initial value, it keeps the previous letter inserted. newValue="text", old value="tex". I want to keep the initial value after changing the input field, for example: oldValue="day", newValue="night"

Comment: I want to keep the old value, the initial one, before modifying the text field

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Also maybe update your question, because the title literally asks for the *previous* value, which is apparently not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the entire string of the old value you have to implement the `.onSubmit` modifier because if the text field is bound to `name` the value changes on each keystroke.

You could add a third `@State` property `text` and swap the values on submit

```
struct TextFieldView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var oldName = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Name", text: $text)
                .onSubmit {
                    oldName = name
                    name = current
                }
            Text(oldName)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no simple solution for this in Swift? Like add a constant variable?

Comment: This is a pretty simple solution inside a SwiftUI view.

Comment: I tested, it does not work

Comment: Please see the *refactored* answer.